# How to install vim-latex plugin?

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I have downloaded `vim-latex-1.9.0.tar.gz`. Then I follow the instruction describe [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download). But, the plugin doesn't run.

My `.vimrc` looks like -

```
set showmatch
inoremap { {}<Left>
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>O
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap < <><Left>
"inoremap "\begin{document}" "\begin{document}<CR>\end{document}<Esc>O"





" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
set shellslash

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

and `/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` looks like-

```
" this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
" of indentation.
set sw=2
" TIP: if you write your \label's as \label{fig:something}, then if you
" type in \ref{fig: and press <C-n> you will automatically cycle through
" all the figure labels. Very useful!
set iskeyword+=:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do to install vim-latex manually is download the tarball and extract it in your vimfiles or .vim directory.  The .vimrc and the tex.vim files will change some latex settings, but do not effect installation.

vim-latex [recommends](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) using a plugin manager like `pathogen` or `Vundle` to install vim-latex.  You can install [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and then enter

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle && \
git clone https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex
```

Note: you will have to make appropriate changes if you work on Windows.  The `~/.vim` directory `~\vimfiles`

PS: your vim.tex file should be a tex.vim file. This won't effect installation, but you won't get your indentation and caption preferences until you fix this.

Comment: I wrote `vim.tex` instead of `tex.vim` I changed my ques.

Comment: `:help latex-suite.txt` shows `E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt` I have downloaded [latex-suite.txt](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.txt) and put under `~/.vim/doc/`