# vim-latex installation issues

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, plugin-pathogen, plugin-managers

This is a copy of a question from TeX stackexchange which in hindsight is likely more relevant here.

I have attempted to install vim-latex (Latex-suite) with Pathogen, though I seem to have (at least partially) failed. I followed the instructions given in the answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-install-vim-latex-plugin).

Though upon following them, `help: latex-suite.txt` yields the message `E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt` (and the same issue occurs with `latex-suite`, which seems to indicate that latex-suite has not been installed properly. If I use `:scriptnames`, I get (among other things) the following lines:

```
 13: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/filebrowser.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/imaps.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
```

which seems to indicate that it is at least partially install. The plugin itself does not seem to work. How should I go about fixing this? I am using vim on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Remove the plugin directory completely and reinstall it using whatever plugin manager you use?

Comment: I dont think reinstalling is necessary unless things really are not working (more info needed). Try running `:helptags ALL` though

Comment: I attempt that but don't have permission normally. If I run vim with sudo, nothing is displayed.

Comment: If you're running Vim with `sudo` then you're running it as a different user (root), so the configuration for your local user won't apply. Use `sudoedit` instead, or copy the configuration to `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I've put together a bunch of resources for how to reporduce the configuration that I've put together for writing LaTeX and Markdown documents in NeoVim. To give you a sense of the plugins which I have configured, see below:

```
" TEXT SUPPORT

" LaTeX Support
    Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
    Plug 'dense-analysis/ale' " LaTeX Linting

" Markdown
    Plug 'gabrielelana/vim-markdown'
    Plug 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'do': { -> mkdp#util#install() }, 'for': ['markdown', 'vim-plug']}
    

" FILE MANAGEMENT

" Startup Screen
    Plug 'mhinz/vim-startify'
    
" File Explorer
    Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons' "adds icons to coc-explorer
    
" Fuzzy Finder
    Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
    Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
    
" Git Integration
    Plug 'mhinz/vim-signify'
    Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'


" AUTOCOMPLETE

" Intellisense
    Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
    Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', {'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
    
" Snippets
    Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Auto pairs and surround for '(' '[' '{' etc.
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs' 
    Plug 'tpope/vim-surround' 
    Plug 'machakann/vim-sandwich' 
    Plug 'tpope/vim-repeat' 
    

" ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS

" Comments
    Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'

" Quick Movements in Text
    Plug 'unblevable/quick-scope'
    Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
    
" Terminal
    Plug 'voldikss/vim-floaterm'
    
" Undo tree
    Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
    
" Multiple Cursors
  Plug 'mg979/vim-visual-multi', {'branch': 'master'}

" Browser Support
    Plug 'glacambre/firenvim', { 'do': { _ -> firenvim#install(0) } }


" MAPPINGS

" Look Up Key Bindings
    Plug 'liuchengxu/vim-which-key'


" APPEARANCE

" Themes 
    Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'  " Source grubox theme
    
" Satus Line
    Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
    Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
```

I've created a [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config/blob/master/CheatSheet.md) which includes all of the key-bindings which I find useful for writing LaTeX documents with NeoVim.
You can find installation instructions on my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config), along with a number of video series on YouTube which demonstrate the [resulting functionality](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDToZ2XXbUGSC7BkorWdyNh3) of the configuration, as well as providing an [installation guide](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDRbxgKSDZ-41U3DF9foKC1J), a [configuration guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyEPY6xFhs0&list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDT0LWxQQma8Yh-IfpmQ7UHr) for adapting my configuration to your needs, and [instructions for using Git to collaborate with others](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIJG4QtZBYI&list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDQYYXIhKKrXhWOaSphnn9ZL). My aim is to provide an out of the box experience with a complete feature set for academic writing, though admitadly installing Vim is a big of a process even with the guided tour I've tried to create. I hope that this is of some use to you!

Comment: Please [edit] and provide as much detail as you can (blockquotes with `>` are fine) in the body of the answer. Link rot is real, and we want each Q&A to stand on its own. It's also hard to judge an answer with the meat of the answer behind many links. Leave the links in though—extra resources are always good.

Comment: cf. [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and **Provide context for links**

Answer (score 0):

If you manually extract a plugin into `~/what/ever/path`, and if its doc is missing (or not up to date if you manually update the plugin), then simply type from Vim:

```
:helptag ~/what/ever/path/doc
```

IOW, in your exact case it should be:

```
:helptag ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/doc
```

That's all.

If for some reasons you've extracted the plugin in a root-write restricted area like `/usr/share`, you'll need to be root to do it, for instance

```
    $> sudo vim -c ":helptag /usr/share/vim/what/ever/path/doc"
```

Please note that

- While vim-latex has a documentation, not all plugins does
- Most plugin managers already take care of that if you use them to take care of plugin installation.
- `'runtimepath'` managers like pathogen do not. However, reading pathogen README

  > Normally to generate documentation, Vim expects you to run `:helptags` on each directory with documentation (e.g., `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`). Provided with pathogen.vim is a `:Helptags` command that does this on every directory in your `'runtimepath'`. If you really want to get crazy, you could even invoke `Helptags` in your vimrc. I don't like to get crazy.

  A solution was already given, but visibly not the minimal one I've just described.

  Note also that pathogen's author recommends using vim8 package feature as it mostly overlaps pathogen intended usage. I haven't checked though if vim packages have a simple way to update plugin documentation as I'm still using a plugin manager (that install plugins and manage `'runtimepath'`)